# Embed excel charts in email body using perl

Tags: linux, excel, perl, email

Is it possible to embed excel charts in email body using Perl on Linux?

I am using Excel::Writer::XLSX module of perl to create charts. I want to send this excel as an attachment (already doing that). But at the same time I would like to have the charts from excel in body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Email::MIME`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME) or `Email::Stuffer` to do that. Just generate your chart with `Excel::Writer::XLSX`, save it in a temporary location and use `Email::MIME` or `Email::Stuffer` to create the message.

The [`Email::Stuffer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer) documentation has a good example of how to do this.

Comment: So happy you are already using CPAN - since it means you won't have any odd requirements to do this "without using a CPAN module" :-) I have not used `Email::Stuffer` on older versions of `perl` but it is written by top notch developers that I'm guessing make use of it @ `$DAYJOB` where a lot of email is sent.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to generate the chart in excel or will need to save it as an image?

Comment: I assumed you were preparing Excel documents with `perl` data munging and `Excel::Writer::XLSX` to write them out. If you want to actually generate the finished charts (and have them appear as BMPs or PNGs ??) then you need to use some method for controlling Excel itself. See @jmcnamara's response below. `Excel::Writer::XLSX::Chart` will write out the chart using Excel's internal format so they will only appear if the receiver's email client can view Excel inline (ugh).

Comment: If you have the data and you have `perl` you can generate charts directly and skip the Excel step all together - but that would be anogher question.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to have the charts from excel in body.

That isn't possible with Excel::Writer::XLSX since it it creates charts in Excel format which is an XML representation of the chart and not an image.

The only tool I know of that can export Excel charts as images is Excel itself. So you would only be able to generate them if you automated Excel using Win32::OLE or similar.